# What happens to running Jenkins builds when Jenkins is preparing for safe shutdown?

Tags: jenkins, restart, shutdown

Does the current running build on Jenkins still completes when you click on "Prepare for Shutdown"?

I want to take admin control on Jenkins to make some config changes so I am clicking on "Prepare for Shutdown" but I want to ensure it completes the current builds before shutting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cloudbees  [describes](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204457744-Why-does-Prepare-for-Shutdown-not-seem-to-work-),

*The Prepare for Shutdown feature prevents any more jobs from running. When all jobs are finished, you still need to restart/stop the instance manually.*

It is the `http://<jenkins.server>/quietDown` command

They also [describe various other options](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-):

```
http://<jenkins.server>/restart
http://<jenkins.server>/safeRestart
http://<jenkins.server>/exit
http://<jenkins.server>/safeExit
http://<jenkins.server>/quietDown
http://<jenkins.server>/cancelQuietDown
```

Personally, I think they should have called it something different, like **setToIdle** or **blockQueue**

In your case, you will want to quietDown, then safeExit or safeRestart (to be safe). Normally you can just safeRestart.

There are some nuances regarding pipelines or jobs that trigger downstream jobs.
There are some plugins that add a button to achieve the same effect.
[Saferestart](https://plugins.jenkins.io/saferestart) just adds buttons.
[Lenient shutdown](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lenientshutdown) talks about downstream jobs and also lets you manage nodes. 
There's other to stop all jobs (bruteforce) and re queue them after (nice admin). Others also manage the queue.

IIRC, pipelines will complete the stage and can resume after the restart or cancel.

Comment: what happens to new build requests? does those requests get piled on?

Comment: According to the [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Queue.Task.html), "Pending Queue.Tasks are persisted when Hudson shuts down". Simple thing to validate; go quiet, trigger task, restart, look for task in queue/executing/completion.